# How do I find variables that should be constants in C?

Tags: c

So, I've got this code:

```
uint8_t* pbytes = pkt->iov[0].iov_base;
```

that creates a pointer to the start of an ethernet packet in a structure.

And I ask my friend to look at the code, and he says: "You're not modifying that, and it would be really confusing if you did, so make it const".

And this seems like a good idea, so:

```
const uint8_t* pbytes = pkt->iov[0].iov_base;
```

or even:

```
const uint8_t * const pbytes = pkt->iov[0].iov_base;
```

And now I am thinking, I bet there are loads of other places where I could have done that, and I bet the compiler is going to be better at finding them than me.

Any ideas how I ask it the question? (gcc preferred, but no problems using a different compiler or a linting tool as long as they will run on unix).

Comment: `const uint8_t* pbytes` is not a constant. C does not have symbolic constants other than _enum-constants_ (which are always `int`)! It is not C++.

Comment: I can't think of any easy way to automate this. You could declare everything `const`, and then remove it for any variables that result in errors.

Comment: The second `const` needs to follow the `*`. `const uint8_t *const pbytes = ...;` defines `pbytes` as a const pointer to a const `uint8_t`.

Comment: @Olaf: True -- `const` means "read-only", not "constant". But the only problem with the OP's question is the use of "constants" in the title.

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks, will fix in question so as not to distract people

Comment: @KeithThompson: `const` does not mean "read only" either. `const` is a guarantee by the **programmer** he will not modify the code. If the compiler puts these variables into a read-only memory area is an implementation detail and not guaranteed by the language.

Comment: Back to your question: You can use `const` qualified objects throughout your code, never modifying an object (just use initialisers). But that would result in problems for dynamically allocated objects and objects passed via pointer.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, `const` means read only. It has nothing to do with read-only memory. To be clear a "constant" expression in C is one that can be (and in some cases must be) evaluated at compile time. `const` means read-only in the sense that attempting to modify the object directly is a constraint violation, and attempting to modify it indirectly (say, via a pointer cast) has undefined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson: A _constant expression_ is something different than `const` qualified objects! For instance, you are not allowed to use such objects in a _constant expression_. Try `static const int i = 10; static int a[i];`! And how you try to modify a `const` qualified object does not matter, both are constaint violations, which mean it invokes undefined behaviour. Seeing them as two different cases is pointless.

Comment: @Olaf: "A *constant expression* is something different than `const` qualified objects!" -- I know that, and I have no idea what I wrote that let you to believe I don't. As for your second point: given `const int n = 0;`, this: `n = 1;` is a constraint violation, while this: `*(int*)&n = 1;` is not a constraint violation, but it has undefined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson: "Yes, const means read only. It has nothing to do with read-only memory. To be clear a "constant" expression in C is one that can be (and in some cases must be) evaluated at compile time." - So how do you get from the `const` qualifier to _constant expressions_? I thought you know better, but that rose doubt, so I had to ask. An unaware reader has to get the impression they are at least somehow connected - which they are not.

Comment: @Olaf: I was *contrasting* `const` and constant expressions.

Answer (score 4):

GCC has a flag to suggest beneficial attributes like const

> -Wsuggest-attribute=[pure|const|noreturn|format] Warn for cases where adding an attribute may be beneficial. The attributes currently
>   supported are listed below.
>
> -Wsuggest-attribute=pure
>   -Wsuggest-attribute=const
>   -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn
>   Warn about functions that might be candidates for attributes pure, const or noreturn. The compiler only
>   warns for functions visible in other compilation units or (in the case
>   of pure and const) if it cannot prove that the function returns
>   normally. A function returns normally if it doesn’t contain an
>   infinite loop or return abnormally by throwing, calling abort or
>   trapping. This analysis requires option -fipa-pure-const, which is
>   enabled by default at -O and higher. Higher optimization levels
>   improve the accuracy of the analysis.

Src: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to apply only to functions.

Answer (score -2):

const propagates. In fact it often becomes a problem and is called "const poisoning". The issue is a function like strchr() which could be called with a const pointer or with a variable one. But if it returns a const *, the string cannot be modified through the pointer, which is often what you want to do.

But if you just make your constant data const at the point immediately after you read it in / initialise it, the compiler will star throwing errors at you every time you try to pass to a non-const qualified context.

Comment: `strchr` is one of a handful of standard library functions that can violate `const`-correctness. It does not imply a fundamental problem with `const`.

Comment: Indeed the problem is rather that the C standard library consists of lots of old, crappily-written functions like strchr. This shortcoming of the standard library is no excuse to write crappy code elsewhere.